# Sending Email on Exit

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, email, asp.net-3.5

I have an application that is written on ASP.NET 3.5 framework that consists of multiple parts. The part that I added to it is involved with, let's say, tasks generation and update. Currently I am trying to add a functionality that sends an email update when I exit from task update.

There are several problems that I need to consider:

1) I need to send an email update when the user navigates from task update to any other part of the application;

2) I need to send an email when the user navigates away from one task to the other (such as manually changes task id in the URL, or opens another task from the favorites);

3) I need to send an email when the user closes the browser.

4) I DO NOT need to send the email update when the user refreshes the task update (clicks refresh button or F5).

I tried to use "beforeunload" jQuery event that fires each time I close the application, navigate away from task update, or refresh the page. I was going to do an ajax call to a web method that would call my send email method. The problem with "beforeunload" is that it does not differentiate whether the task update is being refreshed, closed, or the user navigates away from the page. I need to know that because I do not want to send an email if the user stays on the same task.

I am able to determine if the same task update is refreshed in Page_Load event in code behind or if the user goes to a different task. It does not solve the problem because "beforeunload" event fires before Page_Upload.

The other problem is when the user has multiple tabs open with different tasks...

Has anyone ever implemented the solution for something similar?

Thank you.

Comment: You might be able to check the browser history to differentiate between reload / close window, but that won't scale well with lotsa tabs. If you have some kind of authentication on your page, another idea would be to change 'when user closes browser, send a mail' into 'when users auth runs out, send a mail'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved.

I went ahead and put the update email method in a separate thread. I put a delay on that thread. The delay is being updated on each page load as well as on each AJAX through web method. I also have a timer on the front end that updates the delay for sometime if the screen is idle.